# Including a script src into js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

Im trying to integrate a firebase config into my `js` file rather than directly into html file. Given:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
  .......
  }
</script>
```

and my js file:

```
$(function() {
......
}
```

how can I integrate the line `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>` into my js file ?

Comment: This question has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: Good question. The solution is to 

* Download firebase.js file (to overcome script loading time)
* Create a new javascript file and initialize firebase along with functionalities over here.

* Add  <script src="/js/firebase.js"></script> in the head of the html file.
* Add  <script src="/js/xxxx.js"></script> in the head of the html file.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a tag script and append to body of document.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    script.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: @Pygirl -- this question is about loading an external script into a webpage, without adding a <script> tag to the HTML.  You're probably getting that error because the file is running within node.js, rather than within a browser environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use modular system to stop witting `<script>` tags for dependencies.
Setup firebase from npm, use one of available ways to load module.
There are following ways:

- AMD (RequireJs as example) - import modules asynchronously with such constructions as `require("firebase")`, `define(["firebase"], (firebaseDependency)=>{...});`
- CommonJs - approach which was derived from server side nodeJs;
- ES6 (with babel): `import firebase from "firebase"`;

In this case you'll need to allocate your config separately and import it too.